# Symfony2 logout issue

Tags: symfony

I am testing Security environnement within Symfony2 and hav problem with log out process

Here is my security.yml file

```
security:
firewalls:
    secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            switch_user: true
            logout: 
                path: /logout
                target: /
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/item, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ]  }

providers:
    in_memory:
        users:
            collector:  { password: collector, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
            admin: { password: admin, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Problem is that when I go to mysite.site/app_dev.php/logout it does redirect me to "target" but does not log out active user.

Does anyone know where am i wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using HTTP authentication, the reason might be that your browser caches your credentials and relogins automatically. Try using HTML form authentication and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I guess this is still relevant? No idea how to fix this *without* having to create forms, validations, routs, all that stupid stuff?